# Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT - AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

**Facing issue in the AppDelegate file and below is error message in the console: Please help resolve.**

The error message on the top is : erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

```
2017-09-10 11:53:40.877 Shop[5095:938768] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fde84c1d070'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a546b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109fab141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a5b6134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a4cd840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a4cd3b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000106c49dbb -[UITableView _numberOfRowsInSection:] + 57
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000106e80176 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 2344
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000106e86069 -[UITableViewRowData rectForFooterInSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 508
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000106e861d1 -[UITableViewRowData heightForTable] + 61
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000106c0cdb7 -[UITableView _updateContentSize] + 372
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000106c34baf -[UITableView _rebuildGeometry] + 40
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000106c32bf4 -[UITableView didMoveToWindow] + 145
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000106b90f01 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1737
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000106ba7fc1 -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 84
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000106b90b43 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 779
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000106b90b43 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 779
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000106b83b96 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 151
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000106b83a7d -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 828
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000106b93a0a -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1927
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000106b81cf8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 838
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000106f8ecad -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 616
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000106cb7521 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 3301
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000106cb7a03 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 843
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000106cb8b41 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 58
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000106eaa60c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000106b9755b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1268
    26  QuartzCore                          0x000000010e8b1904 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    27  QuartzCore                          0x000000010e8a5526 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 370
    28  QuartzCore                          0x000000010e8a53a0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    29  QuartzCore                          0x000000010e834e92 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    30  QuartzCore                          0x000000010e861130 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 468
    31  QuartzCore                          0x000000010e861b37 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 115
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a4ec717 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a4ec687 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a4d1038 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 440
    35  UIKit                               0x0000000106ace08f -[UIApplication _run] + 468
    36  UIKit                               0x0000000106ad4134 UIApplicationMain + 159
    37  Shop                                0x00000001058c7d07 main + 55
    38  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010cb0565d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Please remove the image above and replace with the code you use to load data into your UITableView.

Comment: Clearly you set some table view's dataSource to a plain old `UIViewController` instead of a specific view controller class that actually represents the table's dataSource.